# Customer profile

Tags: paypal, authorize.net, recurring

Is there any way in paypal to have something like CIM in authorize.net? We want to create a profile and run a transaction any time. It's for recurring transactions, but we don't want to use [paypal recurring profile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run reference transactions using PayPal.  This would allow you to come back and charge the merchant when ever you are wanting to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this is what we are looking for.